# how do I return a count of items returned from an entityfieldquery

Tags: 7, database

Is it possible to return a count of the number of items returned in an entityfieldquery query?

Comment: do you want to get the result as well as the count? if you just want the count then you could set the query to count. something like $count = $query->count()->execute();

Comment: I think that should do it. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: I have added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

if you just want the count then you could set the query to count.

something like

```
$count = $query->count()->execute()
```

See [here](http://drupal.org/node/1343708) for more detail

Comment: For Drupal 8: `$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->condition('type', "article");
echo $query->count()->execute() . "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

If required you might as well try [Field Count Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_count_formatter) 
It will display the number of item in a multifield